# CodeIgniter Loss The partial Session Data When Move to other page

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I will try explain my problem :

I use CodeIgniter v 2.x. My structure Session when it print look like in my first page:

```
Array
(
 [session_id] => 9952cc1ee3042ed12b2e247cfca4216e
 [ip_address] => ::1
 [user_id] => 1
 [my_json] =>{"mydata":{"123":{"45":"678"}}}
)
```

And then i move to other page and print again the session :

```
Array
(
 [session_id] => 9952cc1ee3042ed12b2e247cfca4216e
 [ip_address] => ::1
 [user_id] => 1
)
```

my_json is disappear. Why it can be happen? and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not possible, check if you are clearing the session data somewhere. Check constructors.

Comment: Can you please share your code? so we can help you better,